# Find queries that return zero results in Solr 4.0

Tags: solr

We are using solr 4.0. I wanted to ask Solr 4.0 provides a built-in log to get queries that fetched n results. e.g. no results, > 100K results, etc.

Looking for anything that solr provides out of the box for getting this kind of data.

If not, is there a suggestion on how to get that data from the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr doesn't provide query logs out-of-the box. Typically this is a feature you want to add yourself based on your needs. Often people will setup another Solr collection to store query logs/click logs etc and structure the data that helps answer the questions they need answered.

Another option is a commercial product like LucidWorks Enterprise which provides click and query logs out-of-the-box.